# SimpleDateFormat convert date incorrect return value when hour is 12

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have having an issue converting dates in a json file to a timestamp. When the hour = 12, the timestamp being returned is incorrect.

Java version 1.8.0_171

Using the code snippet below, I expect the output to be

2017-07-19 07:43:42.0

2017-07-18 08:43:42.0

2017-07-19 09:43:42.0

Instead, I get

2017-07-19 07:43:42.0

2017-07-18 20:43:42.0

2017-07-19 09:43:42.0

I have tried on 2 machines, and had a co-worker run it, same results
Can anyone see what the issue is; I am probably staring at it

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class TimestampTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "2017-07-19T11:43:42.000+0000";
        System.out.println(stringToTimestamp(input));

        input = "2017-07-19T12:43:42.000+0000";
        System.out.println(stringToTimestamp(input));

        input = "2017-07-19T13:43:42.000+0000";
        System.out.println(stringToTimestamp(input));

    }

    private static Timestamp stringToTimestamp(String input) {
        try {   
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(input)) {
                return null;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ",
                Locale.getDefault());
            java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(input);
            Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
            return timestamp;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html: hh is Hour in am/pm (1-12), but your input Strings clearly are in 24hour format and you should use HH instead.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact you shouldn't be using [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) any more, your error is because you are using `hh` instead of `HH`

> h  -> Hour in am/pm (1-12)
>
> H  -> Hour in day (0-23)

Consider using [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) in your case.

Comment: Thank you, for the HH answer. I new I was starring at it an missing it.

Comment: What is recommended to be used instead of simple date format?

Comment: @NickMowen [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are using `SimpleDateFormat` which is by default lenient. If you turn leniency off by setting [`setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.getDefault());
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

You will get an exception saying:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-07-19T13:43:42.000+0000"
```

The root cause here is that you are submitting `13` for hours which requires `HH` pattern instead of `hh`. Because of leniency your code silently fixes the date instead of throwing an exception.

> H Hour in day (0-23)
>
> h Hour in am/pm (1-12)